# Selectively read a formatted data file in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, ifstream, getline, stringstream

I have a data file that begins this way:

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*\
Some useless commented information
\*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //


882
(
(0 0 0)
(1 1 1)
...more vectors
)
```

How do I proceed to read the file and store the number 882 as well as the list of vectors into data structures?

I am essentially trying to use the data within the parenthesis, i.e. (1 2 3) to vec.x = 1, vec.y = 2, vec.z = 3.

Here is my attempt to at least print out the number 882, which it does:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{

  std::string line;
  std::ifstream file ("points");
  if (file.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (file,line) )
    {
            std::stringstream ss(line);
            int n;
            std::vector<int> v;

                while (ss >> n)
                {
                    v.push_back(n);
                }
                std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

    }
    file.close();
  }

  else std::cout << "Unable to open file";

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: I would add checking for blank lines and comment lines before trying to extract numbers.

Comment: Does your "Useless commented information" contain numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on exactly what your formated data file can include as lines.

Assuming your data file follows the following pattern:

```
/* THIS IS BEGIN OF COMMENT BLOCK */
STILL MORE USELESS COMMENTS
812
that 812 is still useless
\* END OF COMMENT BLOCK *\

// **** Single line comment *** //

// **** its fine to have blank lines ***** //

812
(
(1 2 3)
// **** Comments can come anywhere **** //
(4 5 6)
.... MORE VECTORS ...
(7 8 9)
/***** EVENT BLOCK COMMENTS ****/
\***** ******\

// **** Blank lines allowed anywhere **** //
)
```

You can set up a simple state machine to process your data file.

You will have a few states:

```
1. Looking for initial number
   a. Inside Comment Block
   b. Not inside Comment Block
2. Looking for start of list of vectors
   a. Inside Comment Block
   b. Not inside Comment Block
3. Reading list of vectors / Looking for end of list of vectors
   a. Inside Comment Block
   b. Not inside Comment block
```

You have basically 3 things you're looking for. The initial number, the start and end of the list of vectors.
In each of those you have two basic cases that will affect how you handle a line. You're either inside a block comment or not.

If your inside the block comment ignore everything until you find the end of the block comment.

Otherwise process the line to figure out if it is a blank line, start of comment block, comment line, or the thing you're currently looking for.

**The code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct vec{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
};

/* I'll leave these for you to try out yourself. You would know best how each of these are defined */
bool block_comment_start(const string& line);
bool block_comment_end(const string& line);
bool is_number(const string& line);
bool is_point(const string& line);
bool is_start_of_point_list(const string& line);
bool is_end_of_point_list(const string& line);
int parse_num(const string& line){
  int tmp;
  istringstream ss(line);
  ss >> tmp;
  return tmp;
}
vec parsePoint(const string& line){
  vec tmp;
  char lp; /* ignore left parenthesis at beginning of point*/
  istringstream ss(line);
  ss >> lp >> tmp.x >> tmp.y >> tmp.z;
  return tmp;
}

int main(){
    string line;
    int state(0);        /* we're initially looking for a number */
    bool comment(false); /* We're initially not inside a comment block */

    int val;
    vector<vec> points;

    ifstream file("points");
    if (file.is_open()){
      while (getline(file, line)){
        if (comment){
          if (block_comment_end(line))
            comment = false;
        } else if (state == 0){ // Looking for initial number
          if (block_comment_start(line))
            comment = true;
          else if (is_number(line)){
            val = parse_num(line);
            ++state;
          } /* ignore anything that isn't a number or begin of comment line */
        } else if (state == 1){
          if (block_comment_start(line))
            comment = true;
          else if (is_start_of_point_list(line)){
            ++state;
          }
        } else if (state == 2){
          if (block_comment_start(line))
            comment = true;
          else if (is_end_of_point_list(line)){
            ++state;
          } else if (is_point(line)){
            points.push_back(parsePoint(line));
          }
        } /* Ignore everything after end of list of vectors */
      }
    } else {
      cout << "Error opening file: \"points\"";
    }
    return 0;
}

bool is_point(const string& line){
  /* returns true if the first character of the line is '(' and last character is ')'
     this will match anything between parenthesis */
  return line[0] == '(' && line[line.length-1] == ')';
}
```

This is more of an outline of how you can go about parsing your file. What you'll need to do is write the functionality for determining what exactly is a comment line, start of comment block, end of comment block, and so on.

Comment: This is what I needed- thanks.  

I am having trouble with my `bool` statements, however. By printing     

`cout << tmp.x << tmp.y << tmp.z << endl;`  

I get  

`0 0 483848` (tmp.z is different every time).  

An example `bool` statement is, crudely:  

`bool is_point(const string& line)  
{  
    bool found = line.find_first_not_of("(");  
        if (line[found] == '0'){  
            return true;  
        }  
        else  
            return false;  

}`  

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think your is_point function works. It seems tmp.z is unitialized. This is an error.  I added an example of a method to match anything between parenthesis. This is how I would define a point. You may need to change it if that doesn't exactly fit how you would define a point.